# How do I get this if statement with && to work properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancancan

I have this in my view:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.has_role? :admin or :editor %>
```

This returns this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
```

I also tried this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? and current_user.has_role? :admin or :editor %>
```

And while I don't get the above error, it doesn't work at all...i.e. a  `non-signed-in-user` can access the content within that `if` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the more idiomatic way to write this, which is using `[has_any_role?][1]`:

```
    <% if user_signed_in? and current_user.has_any_role? :admin, :editor %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `has_role?` can take more than one parameter. The correct way to do it is:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && (current_user.has_role? :admin or current_user.has_role? :editor) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, try this way:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && [:admin, :editor].include?(current_user.role) %>
```

Comment: Nope...this doesn't work. I get the following error: `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'`